# Set UiCell text color in TableView according indexPath Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swiftui, uikit

I'm trying to display on screen some logs through `UiTableView` and I want to set a red text color to those hasPrefix "root" as following :

```
var logList: [String] = []

...

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.logList.count
    }

        
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableview.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellId", for: indexPath) as! ItemLogCell
        cell.itemLogLabel.text = self.logList[indexPath.row]
        
        print(indexPath.row)
        print(self.logList[indexPath.row].hasPrefix("root"))

        if (self.logList[indexPath.row].hasPrefix("root")) {
            cell.itemLogLabel.textColor = UIColor.red
        }
        
        return cell
    }
```

The problem is even when the prefix condition is false, text color become red and only for some row.

The more I scroll the more there are random red logs.  How can I fix this ?

Comment: The problem is due to dequeuing reusable, please try to have else part of your if condition.

Comment: Override `prepareForReuse()` in your UITavleViewCell subclass and set the default color there. That is called on every cell before reusing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this to reset the color of the other lines :

```
if (self.logList[indexPath.row].hasPrefix("root")) {
   cell.itemLogLabel.textColor = UIColor.red
}
else {
   cell.itemLogLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use instead different `UITableViewDelegate` callback for that

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    guard let cell = cell as? ItemLogCell else { return }

    print(indexPath.row)
    print(self.logList[indexPath.row].hasPrefix("root"))

    if (self.logList[indexPath.row].hasPrefix("root")) {
        cell.itemLogLabel.textColor = UIColor.red
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because UITableViewCell is basically reusable. Imagine that you are seeing there are 6 cells in the screen, index 0 to 5. When you scroll to cell with index 6, the cell with index 0 will be hidden. TableView will not create a new UITableViewCell for the cell 6, it will waste the device's memory. Instead, tableview will dequeue the cell 0 and reuse it. So, cell 6 will has the default value of cell 0. To fix this issue, you will need to set the color again, of the cell that does not has prefix "root"

```
if (self.logList[indexPath.row].hasPrefix("root")) {
    cell.itemLogLabel.textColor = UIColor.red
} else {
    cell.itemLogLabel.textColor = UIColor.black
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As [pham hai](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65457748/14531220) explain cells are reusable so You should consider else case as well. Shorty

```
    let cellColor = cell.itemLogLabel.textColor
    self.logList[indexPath.row].hasPrefix("root") ? cellColor = .red : cellColor = .black
```